# why my laptop is taking about 5 min to boot?

Tags: boot, login, login-screen

I have lenovo ideapad, 16 GB Ram core i7, running Ubuntu 16.04.

Boot time takes about 5 minutes (until I can see Ubuntu 16.04 wallpaper)

What should be done in order to have faster boot?

Comment: Can you add the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` to your question?

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `grep -i -e mem -e sda /var/log/syslog*`. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have the info.